# Trying to make os.makedirs from a list, but check if those folders exist before creating

Tags: python-3.x, list

I can successfully create folders by storing the list of file names and writing to the same directory.

```
import os
folder_source = ('~filepath\filepath')

 str = os.listdir(folder_source)
 res = [sub.replace('.mp4', '') for sub in str] 
 print(res)
 for res in res:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder_source,res))
```

But I'm not sure how I can incorporate if else statement with the (res) variable. So I can add a new location from where the script is located.

```
os.path.exists
if not os.path.exists():
else:
os.removeddirs()
```

Here's where I'm at but it's not working.

```
import os


folder_source = ('~filepath\filepath')

folder_dest = ('~newfilepath\newfilepath')

str = os.listdir(folder_source)

res = [sub.replace('.mp4', '') for sub in str] 

print(res)

for res in res:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder_dest,res))

if not os.path.exists(folder_dest):
    os.makedirs(folder_dest)

else:
        os.removedirs(folder_dest)
```

I'm stuck, any help?

Comment: Just so that we understand what you are trying to do, you want to create directories inside the target directory where their names is based on the names of files in the source directory. If a name from the source directory has a ".mp4" extension discard the extension when creating a directory, otherwise leave it alone. Is that whar you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @EvensF, yes that's correct.  Eventually I'd like to make a pre-designed directories structure based on the files in the source directory.  But the first step was to make directories from the names of files located in a source directory and write those directories to the target directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that?

```py
import pathlib

folder_source = pathlib.Path('~filepath') / 'filepath'
folder_destination = pathlib.Path('destination_files') / 'newfilepath'

source_files = (
    current_file for current_file in folder_source.iterdir() 
    if current_file.is_file()
)

folders_to_create = (
    folder_destination / current_source.stem if current_source.suffix == '.mp4' 
    else folder_destination / current_source.name
    
    for current_source in source_files 
)

for current_folder in folders_to_create:
    current_folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

I have used the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module to make it easier to manage the files.

Comment: thanks a lot @EvensF for this. I'm not familiar with pathlib, so I'll do some digging with it. I'm not sure I follow the syntax of the file path right now.

' ' ' python
folder_source = pathlib.Path('~filepath') / 'filepath' folder_destination = pathlib.Path('destination_files') / 'newfilepath'' 
' ' '

Comment: It's because you can navigate inside a directory represented by a Path object using the / operator and strings. You can see an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators) in Python's official documentation.

Comment: If you feel satisfied, would you consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?